# cUrl with json string and file upload

Tags: php, json, curl, watson, visual-recognition

how do I have to "translate" the following curl command into a valid php curl function?

```
curl -X POST 
     -F "images_file=@fruitbowl.jpg" 
     -F parameters=%7B%22classifier_ids%22%3A%5B%22testtype_205919966%22%5D%2C%22threshold%22%3A0%7D  
     'https://gateway-a.watsonplatform.net/visual-recognition/api/v3/classify?api_key={key}&version=2016-05-20'"
```

It seems that I'm doing something wrong and I can't figure out the problem:

```
$method = 'POST'
$url = 'https://gateway-a.watsonplatform.net/visual-recognition/api/v3/classify?api_key=<myApiKey>&version=2016-05-20'
$data = array(
    array(<file-information>),
    array(<json-string>),
)
$header = array(
            'Content-Type: application/json',
            'Content-Length: ' . strlen(<json-string>),
                )
        )

public function send($method, $url, $data = null, $header = null)
{
    $curl = curl_init();

    switch ($method) {
        case "POST":
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

            if ($data) {
                $postData = $this->renderPostData($data);
                curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postData);
            }
            break;
    }

    if($header) {
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
        curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,$header);
    }

    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    $response = curl_exec($curl);
}

protected function renderPostData($data)
{
    $postData = array();
    foreach ($data as $file) {
        if ($file['isFile']) {
            if(pathinfo($file['path'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION) == 'zip'){
                $postData[$file['name']] = new \CURLFile($file['path'], 'application/zip', $file['name']);
            }
            else {
                $postData[$file['name']] = new \CURLFile($file['path'], 'application/octet-stream', $file['name']);
            }
        } else {
            // this contains the json encoded string
            $postData[$file['name']] = $file['path'];
        }
    }

    return $postData;
}
```

I tried several variations and the Watson Visual Recognition API error is now:

> {
>       "custom_classes": 0,
>       "images": [
>           {
>               "error": {
>                   "description": "Invalid image data. Supported formats are JPG and PNG.",
>                   "error_id": "input_error"
>               }
>           }
>       ],
>       "images_processed": 1
>   }

before it was:

> {
>       "error": {
>           "code": 400,
>           "description": "Invalid JSON content received. Unable to parse.",
>           "error_id": "parameter_error"
>       },
>       "images_processed": 0
>   }

Thank you for your help!

Comment: You are sending `$data`, but your `Content-Length` header pretends the size of the request was only that of `<json-string>`, which ist just a part of `$data`.

Comment: Determining the correct length of the assembled request body should really belong _inside_ such a `send` method ... but first of all, I'd try without it - cURL should be able to figure out the correct value and append that header automatically when you pass an array data structure to CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS

Comment: (Actually, it looks like you are not sending $data, but are looping over that and are only then adding the actual upload files to the data structure ... but in any case, your calculation of the content length seems way prematurely ...)

Comment: thx @CBroe, my issue was a bit different. I have added the wrong value for the $postname in `CURLFile`

Answer (score 0):

My issue was this line:

```
$postData[$file['name']] = new \CURLFile($file['path'], 'application/zip', $file['name']);
```

the last parameter is the $postname. So to fix this issue I had to change this line to:

```
$postData[$file['name']] = new \CURLFile($file['path'], mime_content_type($file['path']), basename($file['path']));
```

and it worked - after I also removed the wrong `$header` completely

:)